# Trying to give a user permissions to all folders on centos

Tags: permissions, centos

I'm trying to give my user on my server permissions to access any folders on the server under the directory `/`.

I've blocked logging in as root to secure against bruteforce attacks so I made a user called `andrew` in a group called `mcadmins`. I do not know how to give the group `mcadmins` access to every SINGLE file in the `/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the user `andrew`to the `wheel` group and use `sudo`. They do not login as root but can run some (or all) commands. [CentOS: Using Sudo](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot#head-5a98c43bd135904d720095ff461d52aa7b51412d)